# Arduino datalogger with google drive sheets

Tags: datetime, google-apps-script

Im trying to make arduino datalogger with google sheets. I need 2 sensor value to be logged with timetable, at least minutes, seconds and hours. From arduino side code and hardware is working and problem comes with google scripts sheet test run. I have tried few different time and var variations but I dont seem to understand it right. In test: ReferenceError: Time is not defined (raw 22, file code), quotes in var now = new Date(hours, minutes, seconds). I have also tried to leave it empty.

```
function doGet(e) { 


Logger.log( JSON.stringify(e) );



var result = 'Ok';



if (e.parameter == 'undefined') {
result = 'No Parameters';



}
  else {
    var sheet_id = '1OJa5ws_IuRba1dfayR8gVhHgrLmQvCEccJm33E3icXU';
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheet_id).getActiveSheet();
    var newRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1; 
var rowData = [1];
var rowData = [2];
var rowData = [0];
var now = new Date(hours, minutes, seconds)
for (var param in e.parameter) {
  Logger.log('In for loop, param=' + param);
  var value = stripQuotes(e.parameter[param]);
  Logger.log(param + ':' + e.parameter[param]);
  switch (param) {
    case 'reading1':
      rowData[1] = value;
      result = 'Written on column B';
      break;
      case 'reading2':
      rowData[2] = value; //Value in column C
      result += ' ,Written on column C';
      break;      

    default:
      result = "unsupported parameter";   
  }
}
Logger.log(JSON.stringify(rowData));
// Write new row below
var newRange = sheet.getRange(newRow, 1, 1, rowData.length);
newRange.setValues([rowData]);


}



return ContentService.createTextOutput(result);
}

function stripQuotes( value ) {



return value.replace(/^["']|['"]$/g, "");

}
```

Comment: Just use `=new Date()`

Comment: How can you define `var now = new Date(hours, minutes, seconds)` if you did not assign to `hours`, `minutes` and `seconds` any values? If what you want to do is to create a current timestamp, it is as easy as defining `var now = new Date();`

Comment: I have tried to leave =new Date() empty or put  there value alone and still same result. Is there something I have to do with sheet itself to make it work? And yes I just want to create current timestamp.

Comment: So your line 22 now contains `var now = new Date();` and this line still gives you the error ` Time is not defined (raw 22, file code)`? Did you deploy your WebApp as a new version since then?